# how to pass arguments from javascript to as3 using external interface

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, arguments

I found how to call actionscript from javascript, but I need to pass some arguments too (dynamic),how can I do this?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendMsg", generateMsg);

function generateMsg(str):void {
    trace(str);
}
```

JS:

```
msg = "";
function setMsg(myMsg) {
    msg = myMsg;
    SendDataToFlashMovie(myMsg);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell him what to do in JS

Comment: hi Edward, what about the javascript file (in order to send the argument).

-- edit: Marcelo already pointed this, sorry for the double comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you have to call the function on the flash object.

I use the following javascript function to get the flash object

```
function GetSWF(id) {
    if (window.document[id] != null)
        if (window.document[id].length == null)
            return window.document[id];
    else
        return window.document[id][1];
    else
    if  (typeof(document[id]) == 'undefined')
        return $('#'+id)[0];
    else
    if (document[id].length == null)
        return document[id];
    else
        return document[id][1];
}
```

then call the function as follows

```
var flash = GetSWF('idOfSWF');
if (typeof flash.sendToActionScript === 'function'){
    flash.sendToActionScript(yourObject,orParameter);
}
```

the AS3 would look like follows

```
if (ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript",receivedFromJavascript);
}
function receivedFromJavascript(myObject:Object,myParameter:String):void{
    // Do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Just noticed that I have a small usage of jQuery in the GetSWF function. I'll take a look and try and remove that. (Its the line `return $('#'+id)[0];`)