# How to find the video url a loaded swf plays?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, video

I am loading a swf component that belongs to a third side.

It plays internally a video using a flash Video object.
I have access to the video object - but i can't deduce from it the url its actually attached to.

( there is not video.getAttachedNetStream )

Is there some way to find out what is the video url?
Either from the loader swf or from the loading browser.
(i tagged it JS because maybe there is a way to retrieve it from the flash browser object some how
like plugins do. I.e. firebug)

tnx
Hed

Comment: try to use Chrome' Dev Tools Network tab: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview

Comment: We are using this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

as an option, but it's only for chrome (the only browser which internalize the flash plugin) and has other issues (like a limited url stack)
- still hoping for a flash direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it from flash.
But there is a workaround. You can pass the video url from JavaScript if the url is known on JavaScript side. All you need is to register a callback in your flash app and call it from JavaScript.
You can find more details here: [how to pass arguments from javascript to as3 using external interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889667/how-to-pass-arguments-from-javascript-to-as3-using-external-interface)